# Keyboard is not present in custom keyboard extension

Tags: swift, keyboard, custom-keyboard

i am using [https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard] when select my theme from keyboard then i dismiss keyboard then after keyboard is not present. i already try to

```
self.view.becomeFirstResponder()


    //OR using dummy textField


    let textfied = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(textfied)
        textfied.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But, its not working in UIInputviewController.

Description : I required to dismiss/present keyboard because user selected them from keyboard then Theme data is not load at a time. so, i want dismiss and present keyboard because theme data is proper load on custom keyboard extension.

Comment: Are u set the delegate??

Comment: yes i already use @Sanjukta